# Polymorphism on Angular 4 gives error: Property 'childs field' does not exist on type 'parent' during interpolation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I am trying to use polymorphism with Angular 4. 
However, when trying to access the member in child class, the compiler '**ng build --prod**' gives error: **/$$_gendir/app/app.component.ngfactory.ts (23,38): Property 'bark' does not exist on type 'Animal'.**

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you.

**app.component.html:**

```
<div *ngIf="isDog(family)">
    <!-- Property 'bark' does not exist on type 'Animal'. -->
    <h4>{{family.bark}}</h4> 

    <!-- Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column 9 -->
    <h4>{{(family as Dog).bark}}</h4>
</div>
<div *ngIf="isCat(family)">
    ...
</div>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

export class Animal {}

export class Dog extends Animal {
  bark: string;
}
export class Cat extends Animal {
  meow: string;
}

const sampleData: Animal = { 'bark': 'wof'} as Dog;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';
  family: Animal;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.family = sampleData;
  }
}
```

Comment: But `Property 'bark' does not exist on type 'Animal'` What do you expect?

Comment: You can try  `family: Dog;` then typescript should not complain after angular compilation

Comment: I would Iike to do 
 `<div *ngIf="isDog(family)">{{family.bark}}</div>`
 `<div *ngIf="isCat(family)">{{family.meow}}</div>`

so I would like to keep `family: Animal;`

Answer (score 0):

you want a method on family

makeNoise()
noise

A family cannot bark, you have not put anything on it. In the makeNoise method, you can then call the noise property on the family (which you can add). See notes on polymorphism (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science).